# How do I design my database for storing likes on comment and posts?

Tags: python, database, flask

I want a to give functionality where one can give like on both comment and post. Do I need to create two separate tables for post-like and comment-like?

This is my code:

```
    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    bio = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False) #new
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False,default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False) #As hashed password will be 60 char long.
    posts = db.relationship('Post',backref='author',lazy=True) #Capital P as we are referencing actual Post class.
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='liked_by',lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):         #This is how our object will be printed when printed out.
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.image_file}','{self.bio}' )"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,default = datetime.utcnow) #Here we are not using utcnow() bcoz we want to pass this as an argument.
    last_edited = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True,default = datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),nullable=False) #Here u as for foreign key we are ref. column and table name.

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}','{self.date_posted}')"


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    published = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,default = datetime.utcnow)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    content_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Comment('{self.author_id}','{self.published}','{self.content}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what kind of functionality you want from the website.

Do you want the user to be able to get a list of all users that liked their post or comment? if so then you need to create another table with userid and postid or commentid.

if you don't want that then you can just add another column to your existing tables called likes and increment it every time a user likes that comment or post

Comment: yes, I want to get the list of people that have liked post or comment. Do I need to inherit the User class in Comment_like and post_like table?

Comment: Then you will have to create two tables, one containing the UserId and PostId and another one containing UserId and CommentId. Every time a user likes a comment or post, add that entry to the table and delete the entry if the user clicks the button again. You can get the list of users that liked it by filtering it by Post/CommentId

Comment: Okay Thank you!!